# Difference between these two Javascript code constructs

Tags: javascript, object

I happened to chance by the following javascript code and it works beautifully.

```
var Mario = {
  name: 'Mario',
  sayHello: function(name) {
    return 'Hi I\'m ' + this.name;
  }
};

var Luigi = {
   name: 'xoxox'
};

alert(Mario.sayHello.call(Luigi , name));
```

However, when i change the property 'name' to something else (say 'xyz'), like so :

```
var Mario = {
  xyz: 'Mario',
  sayHello: function(xyz) {
    return 'Hi I\'m ' + this.xyz;
  }
};

var Luigi = {
   xyz: 'xoxox'
};

alert(Mario.sayHello.call(Luigi , xyz));
```

It doesn't work!!

What does this behaviour signify and why isn't it working? Can someone explain?

Comment: do you have global variable `name`?

Comment: yep you have global var `name` in window

Answer (score 3):

Well, technically, your `name` example doesn't work. It is executed because there is a variable called `name` in the global namespace (`window.name`).

Answer (score 0):

Both are not working, the reason being you are passing a second, not defined, value to the invocation of `call`, you might want to do

```
var Mario = {
  name: 'Mario',
  sayHello: function() {
    return 'Hi I\'m ' + this.name;
  }
};

var Luigi = {
   name: 'xoxox'
};

alert(Mario.sayHello.call(Luigi));
```

There is no need to pass `name`, since that's already in the object.

Answer (score 0):

The mistake is here:

```
var Mario = {
  name: 'Mario',
  sayHello: function(name) {
    return 'Hi I\'m ' + this.name;
  }
};
```

sayHello is a function that gets name as a parameter and does nothing with it. Instead it returns a string with the property `name` of the object the function was called on.

```
Mario.sayHello() // Hi I'm Mario
Mario.sayHello.call({ name: 'Foo'}) // Hi I'm Foo
```

When you do `Mario.sayHello(myname)`, the function sayHello is called in the context of Mario with the `name` parameter initialized to whatever is in myname (could even be an error if myname does not exist).

If you want to give the property-name as parameter you can do:

```
var Mario = {
  name: 'Mario',
  sayHello: function(name) {
    return 'Hi I\'m ' + this[name];
  }
};

var Luigi = {
   xyz: 'xoxox'
};

alert(Mario.sayHello.call(Luigi , 'xyz')); // Hi I'm xoxox
```